# Xbox One web store unavailable in EU?

Tags: xbox-network, xbox-one

Buying a game straight from the console's store works.
But, whenever I try to head over to https://store.xbox.com/en-GB/ it redirects me to the en-US version. This is frustrating and annoying, because prevents us EU residents from buying games online and launch the download remotely (which is kind of important, especially now that most of the games weight around 30gbs). Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? Microsoft Support hasn't come back with an answer in more than two weeks now

Comment: is it the same issue if you use Smart Glass?

Comment: I disabled it, will try later when at home and can re enable it

Comment: The site may be attempting to [detect the browser locale](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673905/best-way-to-determine-users-locale-within-browser). You may want to check your Windows PC's Regions and Languages dialog and make sure the Location tab shows the correct country.  No idea if the Keyboard language would make a difference here... I'd hope not, though.  (I have no idea where this would be controlled on OSX or Linux)

Comment: To add to what Powerlord says, the locale is more often defined at the browser level than the OS. What stage have you gotten up to on the en-US store? What territory are you actually in? I've managed to buy things on the web store from the UK. I think if you get to the point where you're clicking to buy it, it should sign you in and display the correct region for your account (with correct pricing) before you confirm the transaction.

Comment: As a disclaimer, to avoid "easy fixes", I work as a web dev so all those browser-related things have been checked more than once now! Even tried with proxies, still won't change a thing. The x360 store stays in en-GB, while the xOne redirects. @tzhx: I get to the point where I click on "buy" and it redirects me :( Not very far. Tried up to the address form, where it's prompting for a US address, which is what's blocking.

Comment: The locale is, as far as I know, based on cookie data. Scroll to the bottom of your page on xbox.com and set your location to the correct one. I presume you live in the UK so choose United Kingdom. This usually works for me until I reset my cookies.

Comment: Done that as well, tried also with the smartglass option suggested above. Still, us prices and us store overall... This is so annoying

Comment: What is it asking you for an address for? Payment method? I have these details saved (or linked to PayPal or something). I see us prices until, it asks me to sign in and confirm, but then it works fine and charges me in gbp

Comment: I have my main card registered as well (otherwise wouldn't be able to purchase from within the console) and it's showing up. But I have my UK address registered, and the website still asks me for one when I try to purchase. It's really weird.